# Is there a better method of adding an element to an array than iteration?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

Whenever I need to add an element to an array I've always used this algorithm

```
data toAdd = 10;

data[] theArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

data[] tempArray = new int[theArray.Length + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < theArray.Length; i++)
{
    tempArray[i] = theArray[i];
}

theArray = new data[tempArray.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < theArray.Length; i++)
{
    theArray[i] = tempArray[i];
}

theArray[theArray.Length - 1] = toAdd;
```

However I was wondering if there was a better way to do this, as with much larger arrays this will require a large amount of computing time.

Comment: Arrays are fixed-size, `List<T>` (or any of a multitude of other collections) aren't. First verify if you're trying to screw something with a hammer. Then look at `Array.Copy`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.Resize`. But you should really use an `ArrayList` or `List<>` which do this much more easily and effectively.

Comment: Upvoted. But don't use `ArrayList`, prefer the generic `List<>`.